Do research groups welcome students from other universities who want to contribute to research to strengthen their research profiles?
During my BS degree, an undergraduate colleague mentioned that she was working with a research group from another country, possibly French. It wasn’t an internship, and I assumed she reached out to them to volunteer her contributions. Do research groups offer opportunities like that to students, outside of formal internships? If yes, what’s the usual protocol for approaching them? I imagine they receive many such inquiries, so do they mainly consider exceptional students, or is there more to it?

This is probably going to vary country to country and place to place. Here in the UK there are very strict rules around unpaid internships and volunteering, and it would usually be illegal for a research group to agree to accept help from an undergrad, irrespective of their motivation, without an official, and paid, internship position, as all people providing labour under the direction of another person needs to be paid at least the minimum wage except in a very narrowly defined set of circumstances.

First, in order to be accepted you need something to offer. You probably don't need to be exceptional, but something beyond the mundane. "Welcome" student participation may be too strong in most cases. And, you need a motivation beyond strengthening your own research profile.
Second, you need a way to make contact in a way that won't be ignored. Research groups are busy, often too busy, as they likely have other responsibilities. Many "cold" emails are likely to be ignored and immediately trashed when they come from students at other institutions.
One way that is at least a bit more promising is to have a professor make first contact on your behalf. This is best when they know someone in a research group as well as knowing what it is that you have to offer, even if it is just a willingness to work hard. It is harder to ignore an email from someone known, or even someone unknown whose reliability can be assumed.
And if someone else says how great you are it has more weight than you saying the same thing.
Third, do some research so that you know you are a good match for their needs. I wouldn't try to join a French group not knowing the language, for example, or a physics group not having at least a few of the elementary courses (and maybe one or two advanced courses). You want to be seen as probably having a net positive contribution to a group, even if you will be doing some low level, low priority, things.
Good luck. There are no guarantees. In essence you are asking for some sort of mentorship. And mentoring is an added task for people who do it consciously.

Well the motivation is that i obviously wanna pursue graduate studies .My interests lie in early universe cosmology and high-redshift astronomy and i did contact local research groups but that kind of research is not happening in my country. It's mostly high energy physics here. Since my BS thesis was on CFD , i'm wanting an experience very close to my field of interest. What would be a mature way of emailing a group? Should i mention my skills/what i can offer and let them decide the way i can contribute  OR should i be very specific and tell them the area i wanna work on ?

So, it depends on what your main goals are here. Most PhD students need help to do their research (usually a lot of work that might not be as exciting as doing research but a good way to find yourself in a published paper), and most labs have some budget to hire undergrad students to assist them. It is mostly a case of knowing your research interests and which labs might have a space for you.
During my master's, I had one student approach me with the exact same idea, and after talking to my supervisor, we agreed that he would be part of the project. Mind you, he didn't receive a dime during the project. It was mostly a side project for him, but in exchange for his help, I had to teach him everything about my research topic and also programming (mostly the packages we used) and how to do some things I needed him for. Again, this was not exciting research work he was doing, but he ended up being part of our published paper, which he used afterwards to get into his master's program.
I would say that if you want to find a position like this, it is best to contact PhD or Master's students since they usually have more time and are the ones who need help. Postdocs and professors will probably ignore your email or not know if there is an actual need for an extra set of hands.
Most labs (at least in the UK) have a website with their publications. That would be a great place to start. Find titles that interest you and read their work. If you still want to work with them, try contacting them. Most post-graduate students I know also appreciate helping people pursue their research interests.
Good luck to you!

I don't know why this was downvoted. I think undergrads working closely with master's students, all under the supervision of the professor running the group, makes a lot of sense.

I don't know either, and that is what happens in my PhD program and during my master's. Most undergrad students look for experience to improve their applications, and most post-graduate students need extra hands. Maybe people don't like that this is unpaid work? Or it might be specific to my field.
